# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'eventpublisher' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application. I annotated a class of the project with @Component annotation. Now in my main class, when I am trying to get a bean of the class, I get an exception that it was not able to find the bean.

```
Exception in thread "main" [2m2017-05-08 09:53:55.303[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9112[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[       Thread-2][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4df828d7: startup date [Mon May 08 09:53:54 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'eventpublisher' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at com.fannie.SpringEventGenerationJBsApplication.main(SpringEventGenerationJBsApplication.java:17)
```

My class that is annotated as component is following

```
@Component
public class EventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void eventpublishers() {
        ActualEvent actualEvent = new ActualEvent(this);
        System.out.println(actualEvent);
        publisher.publishEvent(actualEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.fannie"})
public class SpringEventGenerationJBsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringEventGenerationJBsApplication.class, args);

        EventPublisher ep = (EventPublisher) context.getBean("eventpublisher");

        ep.eventpublishers();
    }
```

Comment: Bean names are generated from the class name with a lower case first character... So `EventPublisher` would become `eventPublisher` NOT `eventpublisher`.

Comment: Thanks that works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.Deinum maybe you should add that as an answer. You just solved my problem and it would be awesome if I could, at least, upvote you.

Comment: @DP3 please accept `@M.Deinum` 's answer when he writes it. It worked for me and for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beanname)

> Spring generates bean names for unnamed components, following the rules above: essentially, **taking the simple class name and turning its initial character to lower-case**

So when having a class `EventPublisher` which is detected by component-scanning the resulting bean name will be `eventPublisher`.